# product attachment is not shown on cart page after security patches installation

Tags: supee-6788

after installing magento security patches, product attachents stopped to work correctly. here is how they are shown now on cart page:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/imbdx090udk56ik/shot_160621_191332.png

```
a:10:{s:4:"type";s:10:"image/tiff";s:5:"title";s:27:"get coupons and promos.tiff";s:10:"quote_path";s:69:"/media/custom_options/quote/g/e/0f4c8541369bfc38a590d58511c0a048.tiff";s:10:"order_path";s:69:"/media/custom_options/order/g/e/0f4c8541369bfc38a590d58511c0a048.tiff";s:8:"fullpath";s:108:"xxx/custom_options/quote/g/e/0f4c8541369bfc38a590d58511c0a048.tiff";s:4:"size";s:6:"817482";s:5:"width";i:1464;s:6:"height";i:1313;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"0f4c8541369bfc38a590";s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";N;s:3:"key";s:20:"0f4c8541369bfc38a590";}}}
```

is there a block type I need to whitelist?